# Nginx rewrite question mark

Tags: redirect, nginx

I want to redirect an url like 
http://my-site.fr/?param1=xx&param2=xx&param3==xx to the homepage but that doesn't work.

Could you help me ?
I test many syntax but nothing work correctly

```
rewrite ^/?param1=xx&param2=xx&param3==xx http://my-site.fr permanent;
```

Could you help me ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `?` and anything following is the query string and is not part of the normalised URI used by `nginx` in `location` and `rewrite` directives.

You could test for the presence of a query string then use `rewrite` to remove them:

```
if ($args) {
    rewrite ^/$ /? permanent;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.

Answer (score 1):

Syntax :

```
if ($args ~ "(^|&)param1=xx($|&)"){
set $rule_0 1$rule_0;
}
if ($args ~ "(^|&)param2=xx($|&)"){
set $rule_0 2$rule_0;
}
if ($args ~ "(^|&)param3=xx($|&)"){
set $rule_0 3$rule_0;
}
if ($rule_0 = "321"){
rewrite ^/$ /? permanent;
}
```